# Why does grep sometimes show the file name, sometimes not?

Tags: grep, wildcards

Can somebody please explain to me why I don't get the full path in  example 1?

example 1 - returning found line

```
grep MODIFY /opt/releases/packages/cr_c_cr6/sas/dbms/*/*;
outcome: MODIFY
```

example 2 - returning full path

```
grep MODIFY /opt/releases/packages/cr666/sas/dbms/*/*;
/opt/releases/packages/cr666/sas/dbms/sti/FA_DISCLOSURE.ddl:MODIFY QUANTITY NUMBER;
```

I have found a solution, but I want to understand what is happening here. 1 command, different outcome/handling.

Comment: already found the option to use: -H
-H is the default when grepping on multiple files. In case of agrep on 1 file (which is the case with example 1) the -H is not in place.

Answer (score 18):

In your first example, the glob must have expanded to a single file. In that case, `grep` doesn't (by default) prepend the file name.

The second example must have expanded to several file names, and `grep` does prepend the filename in that case.

You can use the `-H` option to always get the filename prepended to the output, or `-h` to never get it.

If your grep lacks these options, you can use `grep REGEX /path/to/pattern/* /dev/null` to always get the filename (there's never any hit in `/dev/null` but it counts as a file name), or `cat /path/to/pattern/* | grep REGEX` to never get a filename.