# Grep -H not always returning file path when two matches are on the same line

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am using grep to recursively look through files and pull out all strings matching a pattern. I want to print the file path: matched string.

```
-H should print the file path for each entry

-o should print just the matched string, omitting everything else on the line I don't want

-r recursive search.
```

I run:

```
grep -Hro [pattern] .
```

Most of the matches print with the filename, however a few just print the matched string. Are -H and -o mutually exclusive in that -o is trimming the filename? 
Sample Output:

```
./path/foo.txt: foo
./path/bar.txt: foo
./path/baz.txt: foo
foo
./path/baz.txt: foo
```

The 4th foo match should also have a file associated with it, but it is not being printed.

I am getting behavior similar to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104378/why-does-grep-sometimes-show-the-file-name-sometimes-not), however I am using the -H flag, and the "/dev/null" solution does not work either.

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

EDIT:

After further exploring each match where the regex was not getting the file name, they all occur when two strings are matched on the same line. 
For example this text file

```
foo
foo sometext foo
foo
```

Outputs

```
./path/foo.txt: foo
./path/foo.txt: foo
foo
./path/foo.txt: foo
```

Anyone know a solution to get both matches to print a filename?

Comment: Following your edit: To get further and maybe reproduce the behavior, you should give us the actual line that contains the two "foo", and the regexp you use.

Answer (score 2):

No, `-H` and `-o` are not mutually exclusive. You may have a Carriage Return character in the part that is matched. This would make the following text be written at the start of the line, thus overwriting the file name.

```
$ printf 'foobar\n' | grep -Ho '.bar'
(standard input):obar

$ printf 'foo\rbar\n' | grep -Ho '.bar'
bar
```

Also, since both lines belong to the same file `baz.txt` (if your example is correct), this may also be due to a long line (larger than the screen width) being wrapped to the next line.

```
$ printf 'foo%80sbar\n' | grep -Ho 'foo.*'
(standard input):foo
       bar
```

Whether one of those scenarios may apply to your situation really depends on your search regex and the content of your files.

Comment: You first example actually produces `barandard input):`...

Comment: @StephenKitt Actually, that's what I was expecting but on my terminal I get what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I stand corrected, if your `grep` outputs colour you will indeed only get `bar`. I had tried with a non-colourised `grep` (which does result in `barandard input):`). (The curious can run `printf 'foo\rbar\n' | grep -Ho --color=always '.bar' | od -xa` to understand what’s going on.)

Comment: Nice catch @Stephen, I did notice that redirecting to `hexdump` shows that the text was here but I wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't visible.

Comment: Both of these are great ideas of what could have been happening given no knowledge of the regex or the text file. Exploring to see if either of these were the issue, I found what is causing it and edited my question. I still don't have a solution for the issue however.